# Тэг time - как не запутать поисковики

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка

Есть у нас такой тэг <time>. Хороший пример использования, я так понимаю:

```
<time pubdate datetime="2010-08-16">16.08.2012</time>
```

Единственная причина использования, которая мне приходит в голову, это дать понять поисковикам актуальность информации и все в таком духе.

Так вот, что если у нас есть страница новости с заголовком h1, и проставленной датой. В сайдбаре превьюхи последних новостей, с заголовком, скажем, h4 и аналогичной меткой о времени, но с другими значениями. Как поисковики отреагируют на такую страницу с кучей разных дат? Зависит ли это от тегов-оберток, напрмиер уменьшит ли "вес" значения даты aside? Может есть смысл убрать атрибут pubdate из времени в превьюхах?

Comment: Пример использования таких данных — разбор страницы на модель. Специфические случаи, аналогичные, в чем-то, более общему случаю с data-атрибутами.

Предположим, например, есть у нас таблица, в которой есть даты, в «традиционном» виде. А мы хотим сделать все модно, чтобы было с сортируемыми строками. JS при этом не порадуется разбору то ли «March 18, 2001», то ли «18 березня 2001» то ли вообще «平成13年 3月18日». А вот в pubdate лежит нормальный ISO 8601.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Думаю, что хорошо понимаю о чем вы говорите. Значение дэйттайма в моем примере ведь соответствует ISO 8601?
Вопрос был именно в разных значениях даты на одной странице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поисковые системы, такие как Яндекс и Гугл, должны отреагировать на Вашу страницу, абсолютно нормально. Примеры - блоги, там используется множество публикаций с разными датами и они, блоги, индексируются даже лучше, чем обычные сайты. Но естественно контент в публикациях должен быть уникальным и будет Вам счастье.

*Зависит ли это от тегов-оберток, например уменьшит ли "вес" значения даты aside?*

Не зависит, вес не уменьшится.

*Может есть смысл убрать атрибут pubdate из времени в превьюхах?*

Нет смысла убирать атрибут pubdate, оставляйте все как есть!

Comment: Спасибо, убедили. Достаточно уверенно :)